# derivative of product of integrals from x to infinity

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have been thinking about this for a while, but struggling to find the answer of the derivative with respect to x of the following function V(x). $f(y)$ is an arbitrary probability density function of a random variable $y$.

$$
V(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}f(y)dy \int_{x}^{\infty}yf(y)dy  
$$

Comment: can you apply this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule
and the derivative of the product rule (ab)'=a'b+ba'?

Comment: Not sure how that helps find the integral derivatives?

Comment: Let us say you first want to compute $\frac  d{dx} (\int_x^{+\infty}f(t)dt)$.
If you look at the second equation of that wikipedia page, setting $b(x)=\infty$, $a(x)=x$, you have exactly the derivative you are after (with $f$ and $b$ independent of $x$, so that the last two terms in the right hand side of that equation vanish).
Then for the other factor, just use the same argument, with $f(t)$ replaced by $tf(t)$. Finally, combine using the rule $(ab)'=a'b+ab'$.